# When requesting vote counts, why not wait a second instead of displaying errors?

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, rate-limiting

[image]

Instead of showing this warning, why not have the JavaScript [wait one second](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) before passing the user's request through?

It would be a better user experience, and I have a hard time thinking it would be much more complex than showing the error message.

Comment: so if I press 100 consecutive time, I keep waiting 100s?

Comment: The timing it’s not tracked by the frontend. That’s the actual response to the API request.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I doubt that's what most people are doing when they see this error. ;)

Comment: @yivi Debouncing is still minimally complex even if it's the backend generating the current error.

Comment: It is still more complex than just doing nothing and present the actual error to the user. Who now knows why they have to wait instead of thinking _“this site is so slow”_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that error message is a server-side error.

The front-end doesn't keep track of all kinds of delays you could encounter (Comments, comment flags, vote counts, moderation dialogs, just to name a few)

This means that the front-end wouldn't know that it has to wait a second to perform the action.

---

This would also add a significant layer of complexity for too little gain:

The front-end would also have to inform the user, somehow, that it's waiting to perform the action the user just initiated. While waiting, the initiated action also would have to be blocked from being triggered again.

If the user performs another action during the wait, the "queued" action may have to be cancelled.

Comment: Fair point. I hadn't thought about the fact that there are many delays that would need to be accounted for if you went down that path.

Answer (score 1):

As for "feature-request" - I don't see any need to change this behavior (similar one happens in other cases too like "can't open a dialog before 5 seconds" for close votes):

- it shows that action user tried did not succeed
- it teaches user that some actions are throttled which likely make user to (subconsciously) wait before retrying
- it shows that there is no queued actions in the site's UI - action either succeeds or fails "instantly" rather than popping up some dialog 20 seconds later to respond to some long forgotten click.

Also from development point of view cost of proper retries / queuing for actions is high for not much benefit here. I.e. you can try to design user-friendly automatic retry to showing dialog (like "share") to handle potential failure - consider scrolling to another post and clicking "share" there too.